# ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'appcompat' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-appcompat

Error rising while Building Gradle of a code I found online.

```
    implement "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$project.appcompat"
    implement "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$project.appcompat"
    implement "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$project.appcompat"
    implement "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$project.arch"
    implement "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$project.arch"
    implement "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$project.retrofit"
    implement "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$project.retrofit"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$project.arch"
    implement "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$project.constraintLayout"
    implement "com.android.support:support-v4:$project.appcompat"
```

P.S. Problem is solves as i understood how to use a variable in gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'appcompat' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

It happens because you are trying to use a property `$project.appcompat` not defined in your script.

Update your script with something like:

```
ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0' //or your version
}
```

and then (pay attention, `implementation` and not `implement`)

```
dependencies {
    // support libraries
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing this field here `$project.appcompat`. Go find what's the current version and place it there. I believe [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions) will help.

So your code transforms from `implement "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$project.appcompat"` to implement `"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:1.0.0<or current version>"`

Comment: thanks a lot, i knew that , found this code on GitHub, was just trying to understand the line $project.appcompat

Comment: the `$project_appcompat` is just a way to access a variable project_appcompat in groovy. I believe you know that `build.gradle` is a groovy file. just like you say `String yourString = "blablabla"` in JAVA. if you check that file there should be a variable with that name, if not check the `build.gradle` , project level. Please mark resolved if issue is fixed.